# Speeding up a Query

Tags: postgis, interpolation, performance, tiger

I am using PostGIS/Tiger and I would like to find all locations within ~2 miles (~3218 meters) of a given location.

The location in question is obtained by just doing

```
select geography(the_geom) FROM tract WHERE tract_id = 'x'
```

So putting this query all together, we get:

```
SELECT tract_id FROM tract, 
        (SELECT geography(the_geom) FROM tract 
         WHERE tract_id = '36047055600') AS c(x) 
WHERE  ST_DWithin(c.x, geography(the_geom), 3218)
```

So I'm using ST_DWithin to find all the neighbors.

My query works great but is taking 14 seconds. I put an index on 'the_geom' column in my tract table, but it doesn't seem to help.

How can I improve my query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The index on `the_geom` is close to useless. Since you are using  `geography(the_geom)`, you should index this.

```
CREATE INDEX geog_idx ON tract  USING gist (geography(the_geom));
```

Alternatively, you could just have a geography column.

Comment: WOW - so what I did was add a new column, clone the values of the_geom to be of type geography (I converted them on a new column) then added an index on that new geography column. Goes from 14 seconds to 1/2 a second! thank you so much!